# sklearn Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, machine-learning

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
movdata = pd.read_csv('Movie_collection.csv')
movdata
movdata
```

Collection  Marketing expense   Production expense  Multiplex coverage  Budget  Movie_length    Lead_ Actor_Rating  Lead_Actress_rating Director_rating Producer_rating Critic_rating   Trailer_views   3D_available    Time_taken  Twitter_hastags Genre   Avg_age_actors  MPAA_film_rating    Num_multiplex   Start_Tech_Oscar
0   48000   20.1264 59.62   0.462   36524.125   138.7   7.825   8.095   7.910   7.995   7.94    527367  YES 109.60  223.840 Thriller    23  PG  494 0
1   43200   20.5462 69.14   0.531   35668.655   152.4   7.505   7.650   7.440   7.470   7.44    494055  NO  146.64  243.456 Drama   42  PG  462 1
2   69400   20.5458 69.14   0.531   39912.675   134.6   7.485   7.570   7.495   7.515   7.44    547051  NO  147.88  2022.400    Comedy  38  PG  458 0
3   66800   20.6474 59.36   0.542   38873.890   119.3   6.895   7.035   6.920   7.020   8.26    516279  YES 185.36  225.344 Drama   45  PG  472 0
4   72400   21.3810 59.36   0.542   39701.585   127.7   6.920   7.070   6.815   7.070   8.26    531448  NO  176.48  225.792 Drama   55  PG  395 0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
501 44800   21.2526 78.86   0.427   36624.115   142.6   8.680   8.775   8.620   8.970   6.80    492480  NO  186.96  243.584 Action  27  PG  561 1
502 41200   20.9054 78.86   0.427   33996.600   150.2   8.780   8.945   8.770   8.930   7.80    482875  YES 132.24  263.296 Action  20  PG  600 1
503 47800   21.2152 78.86   0.427   38751.680   164.5   8.830   8.970   8.855   9.010   7.80    532239  NO  109.56  243.824 Comedy  31  PG  576 1
504 44000   22.1918 78.86   0.427   37740.670   162.8   8.730   8.845   8.800   8.845   6.80    496077  YES 158.80  303.520 Comedy  47  PG  607 1
505 38000   20.9482 78.86   0.427   33496.650   154.3   8.640   8.880   8.680   8.790   6.80    518438  YES 205.60  203.040 Comedy  45  PG  604 1
506 rows × 20 columns

```
movdata1 = pd.get_dummies(movdata)
movdata1
```

Collection  Marketing expense   Production expense  Multiplex coverage  Budget  Movie_length    Lead_ Actor_Rating  Lead_Actress_rating Director_rating Producer_rating ... Avg_age_actors  Num_multiplex   Start_Tech_Oscar    3D_available_NO 3D_available_YES    Genre_Action    Genre_Comedy    Genre_Drama Genre_Thriller  MPAA_film_rating_PG
0   48000   20.1264 59.62   0.462   36524.125   138.7   7.825   8.095   7.910   7.995   ... 23  494 0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   43200   20.5462 69.14   0.531   35668.655   152.4   7.505   7.650   7.440   7.470   ... 42  462 1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
2   69400   20.5458 69.14   0.531   39912.675   134.6   7.485   7.570   7.495   7.515   ... 38  458 0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
3   66800   20.6474 59.36   0.542   38873.890   119.3   6.895   7.035   6.920   7.020   ... 45  472 0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
4   72400   21.3810 59.36   0.542   39701.585   127.7   6.920   7.070   6.815   7.070   ... 55  395 0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
501 44800   21.2526 78.86   0.427   36624.115   142.6   8.680   8.775   8.620   8.970   ... 27  561 1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
502 41200   20.9054 78.86   0.427   33996.600   150.2   8.780   8.945   8.770   8.930   ... 20  600 1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
503 47800   21.2152 78.86   0.427   38751.680   164.5   8.830   8.970   8.855   9.010   ... 31  576 1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
504 44000   22.1918 78.86   0.427   37740.670   162.8   8.730   8.845   8.800   8.845   ... 47  607 1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
505 38000   20.9482 78.86   0.427   33496.650   154.3   8.640   8.880   8.680   8.790   ... 45  604 1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
506 rows × 24 columns

```
x= movdata1.loc[:,movdata1.columns!='Start_Tech_Oscar']
y = movdata1['Start_Tech_Oscar']
x.head()
```

Collection  Marketing expense   Production expense  Multiplex coverage  Budget  Movie_length    Lead_ Actor_Rating  Lead_Actress_rating Director_rating Producer_rating ... Twitter_hastags Avg_age_actors  Num_multiplex   3D_available_NO 3D_available_YES    Genre_Action    Genre_Comedy    Genre_Drama Genre_Thriller  MPAA_film_rating_PG
0   48000   20.1264 59.62   0.462   36524.125   138.7   7.825   8.095   7.910   7.995   ... 223.840 23  494 0   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   43200   20.5462 69.14   0.531   35668.655   152.4   7.505   7.650   7.440   7.470   ... 243.456 42  462 1   0   0   0   1   0   1
2   69400   20.5458 69.14   0.531   39912.675   134.6   7.485   7.570   7.495   7.515   ... 2022.400    38  458 1   0   0   1   0   0   1
3   66800   20.6474 59.36   0.542   38873.890   119.3   6.895   7.035   6.920   7.020   ... 225.344 45  472 0   1   0   0   1   0   1
4   72400   21.3810 59.36   0.542   39701.585   127.7   6.920   7.070   6.815   7.070   ... 225.792 55  395 1   0   0   0   1   0   1
5 rows × 23 columns

```
y.head()
```

### 0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: Start_Tech_Oscar, dtype: int64
clsmov = LogisticRegression()
clsmov.fit(x,y)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6736\2033513903.py in 
----> 1 clsmov.fit(x,y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model_logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
1506             _dtype = [np.float64, np.float32]
1507
-> 1508         X, y = self._validate_data(
1509             X,
1510             y,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
579                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
580             else:
--> 581                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
582             out = X, y
583

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
962         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
963
--> 964     X = check_array(
965         X,
966         accept_sparse=accept_sparse,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
798
799         if force_all_finite:
--> 800             _assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")
801
802     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
112         ):
113             type_err = "infinity" if allow_nan else "NaN, infinity"
--> 114             raise ValueError(
115                 msg_err.format(
116                     type_err, msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have faced the problem that your dataframe might have null data or infinite data

Check it using this command (for nan)

```
np.any(np.isnan(mat))
```

And this command for infinite data

```
np.all(np.isfinite(mat))
```

You can try to change your data in someway and get rid of (or replace) missing data